# How do I create a list index that loops through integers in another list

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have this list:

```
sentences = ['The number of adults who read at least one novel within the past 12 months fell to 47%.', 
'Fiction reading rose from 2002 to 2008.', 'The decline in fiction reading last year occurred mostly among men.', 
'Women read more fiction.', '50% more.', 'Though it decreased 10% over the last decade.', 'Men are more likely to read nonfiction.', 
'Young adults are more likely to read fiction.', 'Just 54% of Americans cracked open a book of  any kind last year.', 
'But novels have suffered more than nonfiction.']
```

And I have another list containing the indexes of all sequences of sentences in the above list that contain a number.

```
index_groupings = [[0, 1], [4, 5], [8]]
```

I want to extract specified sentence sequences in the variable "sentences" by using the indexes in the variable "index_groupings" so that I get the following output:

**The number of adults who read at least one novel within the past 12 months fell to 47%.Fiction reading rose from 2002 to 2008.**

**50% more.Though it decreased 10% over the last decade.**

**Just 54% of Americans cracked open a book of  any kind last year.**

So I do the following:

```
for grouping in index_groupings:
    if len(grouping) > 1:
        print sentences[grouping[:]]
    else:
        print sentences[grouping[0]]
```

When I run that, I get an error message that says

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

The line `print sentences[grouping[:]]` trips it up. Is there a way to loop through those index sequences in the list index_groupings so that it returns the correct output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print ["".join(map(lambda x:sentences[x],i)) for i in index_groupings]
```

You can use `join` and `list comprehension`. here.

Output:`['The number of adults who read at least one novel within the past 12 months fell to 47%. Fiction reading rose from 2002 to 2008.', '50% more. Though it decreased 10% over the last decade.', 'Just 54% of Americans cracked open a book of  any kind last year.']`

Comment: What would be the best way to also pull the sentence directly before and directly after the sequence without triggering an "out of index range" error if sequence falls at beginning or end of list. I tried this: [" ".join(map(lambda x:sentences[x -1] + sentences[x] + sentences[x +1] ,i)) for i in index_groupings]  but it causes sentence repeats because of the index sequences.

Comment: For example, if we take the output "50% more.Though it decreased 10% over the last decade.", I'd want to pull the sentence before and after it so that the output is "Women read more fiction. 50% more.Though it decreased 10% over the last decade. Men are more likely to read nonfiction."

Comment: @MikaSchiller u want this on some condition or for all

Comment: For all...the sentences who's indexes have been captured in the variable index_groupings.

Answer (score 0):

Python's got some batteries for this:

```
for grouping in index_groupings:
    if len(grouping) > 1:
        print sentences[slice(*grouping)]
    else:
        print sentences[grouping[0]]
```

The `slice` constructor is used under the hood when you do `a[x:y:z]` (it gets converted to `a[slice(x, y, z)]` except specialized byte codes are used to avoid some overhead), this is just creating one explicitly since we have the sequence of values needed to call the constructor anyway, and it's more convenient than indexing or unpacking and then using slicing syntax.